# Why i can't reach this array in json

Tags: android, arrays, json

I'm trying to get this array of images in this json bellow and display it in GridView but i don't know why i can't reach that

```
[
  {
    "id": 385,
    "title": "this title",
    "image": "logo.png",
    "description": "description ",
    "images": [
      "logo.png",
      "image1.png"
    ],
    "user_name": "my name",
    "telephone": "0123456789",
    "city_name": "جدة",
    "created_at": "2017-03-20T17:51:16+00:00",
    "time_ago": "6 days ago",
    "user_id": 159
  }
]
```

and this is my full AyncTask.

```
     private class AysncImages extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            // pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            // pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            // pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            // pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            // Building Parameters
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(String.valueOf(Config.BASE_URL));

            //jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url + 373); //or url + ID
            Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground Image: " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try 
                {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    JSONArray arrayObj = jsonObj.getJSONArray("images");

                    Log.i(TAG, "array: "+ jsonObj);

                    GridItem item = new GridItem();
                    for (int i = 0; i < arrayObj.length(); i++) {
                        String images = arrayObj.getString(i);


                        Log.i(TAG, "parseResult: " + jsonObj);
                        item.setImage(IMAGE_LINK + images);//IMAGE_LINK +

                        Log.i(TAG, "parseResult: " + IMAGE_LINK + " " + images);
                        mGridData.add(item);

                    }
                    // Getting JSON Array node
                } catch (JSONException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            // if (result == 1) {
                mGridAdapter.setGridData(mGridData);
            //} else {
            //  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed to fetch data!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // }

            //Hide progressbar
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

In my log i can't reach `jsonObj` or `arrayObj` I just can reach `jsonStr` what i'm missing ?

my Log for jsonStr

[image]

Comment: post your full json response i did not see any array tag name: `images`

Comment: your json is not vaild

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 please check my json there is `images: [
"logo.png",
"image1.png"
]`

Comment: full json response should be in JsonObject and post your full json

Comment: then how my json shoud be like ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
try {
    JSONArray jArr = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
    for (int i = 0; i < jArr.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject Obj = jArr.getJSONObject(i);
        String id=Obj.getString("id");
        String title=Obj.getString("title");
        String description=Obj.getString("description");

        JSONArray image_arr=Obj.getJSONArray("images");
        for (int j = 0; j < image_arr.length(); j++) {
            String value=image_arr.getString(j);
            Log.d("TAG","value:"+value);
        }
    }
 } catch (JSONException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way..

```
try {

            JSONArray arrayObj = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayObj.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = arrayObj.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONArray arrayObjImage = jsonObject.getJSONArray("images");
                String image1 = arrayObjImage.getString(0);
                String image2 = arrayObjImage.getString(1);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of, look at your Json definition:

```
[
  {
    "id": 385,
    "title": "this title",
    ...
  }
]
```

And also look at how you are accessing your Json in your code:

```
String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(String.valueOf(Config.BASE_URL));
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
JSONArray arrayObj = jsonObj.getJSONArray("images");
```

In your code, `jsonObj` is supposed to be the root object of you json, but if you look carefully, your json **does not have a root node**. You Json is, at the root level, an *array*. That's why you cannot access `jsonObj` and, therefore, that's why you won't access the `images` array.

To solve it, you have 2 options:

1) Make the server return an object instead of an array by removing the `[` and `]`. E.g.

```
{
    "id": 385,
    "title": "this title",
    ...
}
```

2) Change your code to starting reading the root as the first position of your array. E.g.:

```
String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(String.valueOf(Config.BASE_URL));
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.get(0);
JSONArray arrayObj = jsonObj.getJSONArray("images");
```

(just as a side note: I haven't been programming in Android for a while, so I'm not sure of the correctness of the code above)

If it's possible for you to change the server, option 1 is preferable.